# Manually add library to installed packages

Tags: apt, package-management, libraries

I'm trying to install opencv libraries. There were some dependencies that apt can't locate:

```
libcudart4
libcufft4
libnpp4
```

These libraries are part of CUDA from nvidia. So I installed CUDA and now I have the following additional libs:

```
libcudart.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.4
libcufft.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcufft.so.4
libnpp.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libnpp.so.4
```

(and some more)

However, apt doesn't know about these libs and therefore I still can't install opencv.

So my question is: how can I tell apt that these libraries are installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APT dependencies are not based on files per si, they are based on package names and version.

What you can do is use the "equivs" utility and create a dummy package with the required name/version, for details check:
http://eric.lubow.org/2010/system-administration/creating-dummy-packages-on-debian/